# primes in arithmetic progression in quadratic field

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist any reference on primes in arithmetic progression in  quadratic fields?
Thank you.

Comment: After cursory searching [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238413/primes-in-arithmetic-progressions-in-number-fields) is the "simplest" reference I can find (which may not be useful for you). The relevant search terms are very likely "Chebotarev's Density Theorem", but this may be at a higher complexity than you want.

Comment: I can add [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29190/dirichlets-theorem-for-number-fields) as a further reference. Again, this leads to Chebotarev's density theorem. :-)